# Issue with nested loop and df.append

Tags: python, pandas, loops, scikit-learn, regression

Good morning,

I have the following dataset (making this up since the main dataset is confidential):

```
country     city    total_customer  total_purchase  total_items
France      Paris     2355231         7848589        84454
Germany     Berlin    3211551         5646545        84564
```

I want to run a linear regression for each country and city combination and output it as a final pandas dataframe like the following:

```
country     city      coef1           coef2      intercept
France      Paris     -0.294942     258.471387  -625.582231
Germany     Berlin    1.987         422.4554     454.645
```

I wrote the following code so far (my dataset is small like 10k rows maximum so I am not too worried about performance):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm
countries = df["country"].unique()
cities = df["city"].unique()
df_results = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['country','city','coef1','coef2','intercept'])
for country in countries:
      for city in cities:
            df[(df['country']== country)&(df['city']== city)]
            y = df["total_customer"]
            y = y.dropna()
            x = df[["total_purchase","total_items"]]
            x = x.dropna()
            regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
            if df.empty:
                continue
            else:
                regr.fit(x, y)
                coef1 = regr.coef_[0]
                coef2 = regr.coef_[1]
                intercept = regr.intercept_
                df_results = df_results.append({'country':country,'city':city,'coef1':coef1,'coef2':coef2,'intercept':intercept}, ignore_index=True)
```

The output is the following:

```
df_results
    country  city        coef1       coef2        intercept
0   France   Paris      -0.294942   258.471387  -625.582231
1   Germany  Berlin     -0.294942   258.471387  -625.582231
```

It looks like the results for coef1, coef2 and intercept are gonna be a single output instead of the output of each linear regression run and I cannot seem to fix it so if someone could enlighten me here that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you're fitting the entire df, look after your `for city in cities` you're not assigning your df back to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the first line in your for loop:

```
df[(df['country']== country)&(df['city']== city)]
```

There are a couple things. First, there's no assignment here - you're just stating the filtered dataframe but not storing it in a variable, so later in your calculations you're doing a regression on your entire data set each time.

Second, if you were to do `df = df[<filters>]` you would still have a problem, becuase you'd be shrinking your dataframe each time.

What you want to do is store the filtered dataframe as a new variable, and then use that for your later calculations:

```
df2 = df[(df['country']== country)&(df['city']== city)]
y = df2["total_customer"]
y = y.dropna()
x = df2[["total_purchase","total_items"]]
x = x.dropna()
...
```